# copy file from local to server does work, from server to local does not

Tags: java, smb

We are trying to copy a pdf from server to local folder and we keep getting this error:

Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.

this is the function:

```
public void copyPasteFileFromNetwerkDriveToLocal(String source, String destFileUrl, String destFileName) {
    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {
        
        NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("domain","user","password");
        String remoteDocUrl = "smb:"+source; //The shared directory to store pictures
        SmbFile remoteDocUrlFile = new SmbFile(remoteDocUrl, auth);
        remoteDocUrlFile.connect(); //Try to connect
        
        if (remoteDocUrlFile.exists()) {
            String remoteDocUrlAndName = "smb:"+source;
            SmbFile remoteDocFile = new SmbFile(remoteDocUrlAndName, auth);
            remoteDocFile.connect(); //Try to connect
            
            File localFile = new File(destFileUrl+destFileName);
            
            in = new BufferedInputStream(new SmbFileInputStream(remoteDocFile));
            out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(localFile));

            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int len = 0; //Read length
            while ((len = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }               
            
            out.flush(); //The refresh buffer output stream
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        String msg = "The error occurred: " + e.getLocalizedMessage();
        System.out.println(msg);
    }
    finally {
        try {
            if(out != null) {
                out.close();
            }
            if(in != null) {
                in.close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}
    }       
}
```

but the other way around  does work with the same username and password:

```
public void copyPasteFileFromLocalToNetwerkDrive(String source, String destFileUrl, String destFileName) {
    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {
        //Get a picture
        File localFile = new File(source);
        
        NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("domain","user","password");
        String remoteDocUrl = "smb:"+destFileUrl; //The shared directory to store pictures
        SmbFile remoteDocUrlFile = new SmbFile(remoteDocUrl, auth);
        remoteDocUrlFile.connect(); //Try to connect
        
        if (!remoteDocUrlFile.exists()) {
            //maak alle directories
            remoteDocUrlFile.mkdirs();
        }
        
        String remoteDocUrlAndName = "smb:"+destFileUrl+destFileName;
        SmbFile remoteDocFile = new SmbFile(remoteDocUrlAndName, auth);
        remoteDocFile.connect(); //Try to connect

        in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(localFile));
        out = new BufferedOutputStream(new SmbFileOutputStream(remoteDocFile));

        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int len = 0; //Read length
        while ((len = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        out.flush(); //The refresh buffer output stream
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        String msg = "The error occurred: " + e.getLocalizedMessage();
        System.out.println(msg);
    }
    finally {
        try {
            if(out != null) {
                out.close();
            }
            if(in != null) {
                in.close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}
    }       
}
```

does anyone know what we are doing wrong?

thanks in advance!

sincerely,
laurens wolf

Comment: at a glance i can't tell: 1) whats the protocol being used? perhaps you are missing some tags; 2) have you doubly, no, triple checked the credentials? given the error message says about something wrong in username/password; 3) have you tested the remote using something else but your java code?

Comment: @BagusTesa, the protocole seems to be [SMB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block).

Comment: `catch (Exception e) {}`... Tssk tssk. :)

Comment: Don't restrict the amount of error information in any way. You want ```e.printStackTrace();```

Comment: I will try the e.printstacktrace and post the result here on monday! And yes we use the smb protocol, can it be a problem? Since it does work the other way around? Sorry if there are some major errors we are not java developers here, but we do need to work with java verry occasionally

Comment: we do now get the following error



The error occurred: Transport2 timedout waiting for response to SmbComReadAndX[command=SMB_COM_READ_ANDX,received=false,errorCode=0,flags=0x0018,flags2=0x4803,signSeq=0,tid=2,pid=37412,uid=0,mid=4,wordCount=12,byteCount=0,andxCommand=0xFF,andxOffset=0,fid=0,offset=0,maxCount=8192,minCount=8192,openTimeout=-1,remaining=0,offset=0]